# Python Script in Cloud Function downloading files

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a Python Script in Google Cloud Functions.

One of the parts of the script gets a list of URL's (in String format), which I'm currently storing as it is.

The problem I'm having is that in the local version of that script (the one I run on my computer) I download the files of those URL's into a local folder as I need to store those files in Firebase Storage but with a lower resolution and size.

Here is the code I'm using to download the images:

Here I run the full thing getting the urls, and later changing those URL's into jpg's.

```
#Images Section
                imagesRaw = []
                imagesSection = soup.find('div', {'class': 'src__GalleryContainer-sc-bdjcm0-7'})
                imagesInfo = imagesSection.find_all('img', {'class': 'gallery-image__StyledImg-sc-jtk816-0'})

                image1 = imagesInfo[0].get('src')

                for image in imagesInfo:
                    img = image.get('data-flickity-lazyload-src')
                    imagesRaw.append(img)

                imagesRaw.pop(0)
                imagesRaw.insert(0, image1)

                images = imagesRaw[:12]

                imageFile = []
                
                #Here we will store the images in local file
                for image in images:
                    #First we change the ending from webp to jpg
                    newURL = image[:-4] + 'jpg'
                    print(newURL)
                 
                    name = find_between(newURL, "_img", "/origin.jpg")

                    if name == "":
                        name = random_name()
   
                    print(name)
                    #Here the function to download the image
                    try:
                        dl_jpg(newURL, 'images/', name)
                    except:
                        break
                    #Here we Optimize the image to size 500 x 394 pixels
                    # And get the location for the new image
                    try:
                        path = optimizeImage(name)
                    except:
                        break
                    # We append the path to the Array of paths
                    imageFile.append(path)
```

This is the function I use to download the Image from the URL:

```
def dl_jpg(url, file_path, file_name):
full_path = file_path + file_name + '.jpg'
path = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
```

This is the function where I optimize te Image to my needs:

```
def optimizeImage(name) -> str:
    foo = Image.open(os.path.join('images/', name + '.jpg'))
    foo = foo.resize((525,394),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    foo.save('images/' + name + '.jpg',optimize=True,quality=50)
    print('Optimized Image: ' + name)
    return 'images/' + name + '.jpg'
```

And Finally I get the images stored in Firebase Storage like this:

```
photos = []

        for image in listing.photos:
            fullpath = image #find_between(image, 'scrapping/', '.jpg') + '.jpg'

            filename = fullpath[7:]
            path = fullpath[0:6]

            imagePath = path + '/' + filename
            bucket = storage.bucket()
            blob = bucket.blob('ListingImages/' + ref.id + '/' + filename)
            blob.upload_from_filename(imagePath)
            blob.make_public()
            photos.append(blob.public_url)
```

The problem that I see is that I do have a folder called Images next to my Script in my local, however in Cloud Functions I don't know how to have something similar that can help me to just hold those files while it optimizes and uploads and then just delete the files.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can save the images in`/tmp` in the Cloud Function. Just be careful, `/tmp` is loaded in memory and not in a disk so try to prevent running out of memory

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for that maybe?

Comment: You can check this https://medium.com/@hpoleselo/writing-files-within-a-cloud-function-tmp-to-the-rescue-a47a6b482758

Comment: Hey I'm getting a new issue with the use of /tmp/ basically I changed the the images/ to /tmp/ and it seems like it does the download and the optimization, but at the end when doing the upload to firestorage gives this error: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/h/cabujfoh.jpg'" is like it added a subfolder in this case h  don't know why it added it, an ideas? and where can I visually see the files in tmp?

Comment: Edit or create a new question with these details

Comment: As mentioned by Ferregina, it's a different issue. The issue you had was resolved. You need to open a new question with the new issue you are getting.  Could you please create an answer and post it Ferregina Pelona to help the community with this issue?

Comment: Already Did Andres thank you

Comment: @ReneAlas Are you going to post the solution to your question as an answer?

Comment: Hi Hector please check the answer in my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72985751/problems-using-the-tmp-folder-in-cloud-function