# Problems using the tmp folder in Cloud Function

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use a Folder to deposit images while running a Python Script and storing the result on my Firebase Firestore and the images to the Cloud Storage.

At the moment I have my main Function which runs the storing and the getting of the Images.

An then 3 complement functions that help me with the downloading of the images, optimization (making them smaller and less quality), and the other helps me name the file.

Here the functions:

Download Images Function:

```
def dl_jpg(url, file_path, file_name):
full_path = file_path + file_name + '.jpg'
path = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
```

Optimize Image (make it smaller and less Quality):

```
def optimizeImage(name) -> str:
    foo = Image.open(os.path.join('/tmp/', name + '.jpg'))
    foo = foo.resize((525,394),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    foo.save('/tmp/' + name + '.jpg',optimize=True,quality=50)
    print('Optimized Image: ' + name)
    return '/tmp/' + name + '.jpg'
```

Give Random Name:

```
def random_name() -> str:
    # printing lowercase
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
```

Now on the main Function, I get the images like this:

```
#Images Section
        imagesRaw = []
        imagesSection = soup.find('div', {'class': 'src__GalleryContainer-sc-bdjcm0-7'})
        imagesInfo = imagesSection.find_all('img', {'class': 'gallery-image__StyledImg-sc-jtk816-0'})

        image1 = imagesInfo[0].get('src')

        for image in imagesInfo:
            img = image.get('data-flickity-lazyload-src')
            imagesRaw.append(img)

        imagesRaw.pop(0)
        imagesRaw.insert(0, image1)

        images = imagesRaw[:12]

        imageFile = []
                
        #Here we will store the images in local file
        for image in images:
            #First we change the ending from webp to jpg
            newURL = image[:-4] + 'jpg'
            print(newURL)
            
            name = find_between(newURL, "_img", "/origin.jpg")

            if name == "":
                name = random_name()

            print(name)
            #Here the function to download the image
            try:
                dl_jpg(newURL, '/tmp/', name)
            except:
                break
            #Here we Optimize the image to size 500 x 394 pixels
            # And get the location for the new image
            try:
                path = optimizeImage(name)
            except:
                break
            # We append the path to the Array of paths
            imageFile.append(path)
```

And Finally, in the main function, I upload the images to Firebase Storage and then the array of URLs from Storage inside the new Detail in Firestore

```
ref = db.collection('listings').document()

            photos = []

            for image in listing.photos:
                fullpath = image #find_between(image, 'scrapping/', '.jpg') + '.jpg'

                filename = fullpath[7:]
                path = fullpath[0:6]

                print('FileName: ' + filename)
                print('path: '+ path)

            imagePath = path + '/' + filename
            bucket = store.get_bucket('testxxxxxx2365963.appspot.com')
            blob = bucket.blob('ListingImages/' + ref.id + '/' + filename)
            blob.upload_from_filename(imagePath)
            blob.make_public()
            photos.append(blob.public_url)
```

At the moment my problem is that at the moment it is giving an additional subfolder when uploading with this error:

> "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/h/cabujfoh.jpg'"

Any Ideas how to fix and allow the imges optimized be uploaded.

Comment: You have to make sure you're using the correct file path on your variable `foo`. This line of code: `Image.open(os.path.join('/tmp/', name + '.jpg'))` produces that error. Are you using the correct path for your image?

Comment: Honestly I just change my local path which was Images/ for /tmp/ any guide or advise here

Comment: Where are you saving the image? What's the output of the variable `full_path`?

Comment: Hey sorry to haven't answer before, I found the problem, it was that I was using in my local the folder images/ and now change to tmp which is shorter and in this lines filename = fullpath[7:]
                path = fullpath[0:6] 
I got the route information, so I notice that the full path wasn't correct so I change into this:
fullpath = image #find_between(image, 'scrapping/', '.jpg') + '.jpg'

                fullpath2 = fullpath[1:]
                filename = fullpath2.split('/',1)[1]
                path = '/tmp'

                imagePath = path + '/' + filename
Now Working

Comment: Could you please post it as an answer so that it can also help the community.

Answer (score 0):

For any of you guys, tracking this:

I found the problem, it was that I was using in my local the folder:
`images/`

and now change to tmp which is shorter and in this lines:

```
filename = fullpath[7:] 
path = fullpath[0:6]
```

I got the route information, so I notice that the full path wasn't correct so I change into this:

```
fullpath = image #find_between(image, 'scrapping/', '.jpg') + '.jpg' fullpath2 = fullpath[1:] filename = fullpath2.split('/',1)[1] path = '/tmp' imagePath = path + '/' + filename
```

Now Working